# How do I repair drywall holes around outlets near my counter?

Tags: patching-drywall

We recently had our countertops replaced. The old countertops had a backsplash, and the new ones do not (we're thinking of adding a tile backsplash later on). There is a higher breakfast bar, so a small space of wall between the kitchen countertop surface and the higher bar surface, where there were two outlets.

When removing the old countertops and backsplash, a hole around both outlets was created. Now I'm not sure what the best way to repair the drywall would be in this area - I have seen drywall patches designed to go around outlets, but the space around the outlets seems a bit wider than would be ideal. It seems like it would also be difficult to access the lower area partially hidden by the countertops to patch in a new piece of drywall. Any tips?[image]
[image]

Comment: In one picture the drywall is above the counter, another it's behind.  Odd that counter extends into the drywall?
I hate to say that the right time to fix this was before the counters were installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Cut a rectangle of new drywall that's of substantial size and appropriate for the area to be repaired. I would cover all those screw holes since they're probably weakened behind. Cut out for the outlet box.
2. Trace the patch on the wall with it in its intended position.
3. Cut out the existing drywall on the trace using a keyhole saw and/or utility knife. Be careful to not damage wiring.
4. Float some plywood or scrap lumber behind the cut edge and screw it through the existing drywall.
5. Screw the patch in place.
6. Tape the repair joints.

Be aware of where your studs are and either cut down the center or leave some overhang so you can mount the repair backing. Don't cut right against the edge of a stud and don't cut right against the upper molding. Leave at least a good inch.

Comment: To figure out where the studs are in relation to the hole, stick a tape measure in the hole and run it along the back of the drywall until it hits a stud. Write the measurement on the drywall (you'll be cutting this chunk out shortly, it doesn't matter) and mark the point at which you measured. Add 3/4" to you measurement and measure on the outside of the drywall from your mark and make a 2nd mark. This 2nd mark will be the middle of the stud.

Comment: Also if you get over to a stud, you could toe-nail screw a scrap of wood to support this mess.